# ReactNative IOS stuck on splash screen when cold start from notification

Tags: ios, react-native, push-notification, amplifyjs

I have a ReactNative pp with version `0.63.4` configure with amplify push notification.

When app is closed (not in background) and launched from notification after a long time (i observed when phone is locked for 5/10 mins) app just stays on splash.

This happens in release mode (when build using command line and i also modified schema to build for release ) i don't see much on device logs from console sometimes i see this error being logged `nw_read_request_report [C9] Receive failed with error "Software caused connection abort"` i added `@try @catch` around most of the methods in `AppDelegate.m` as suggested in some threads i read but it didn't help.

I have also added some console.error (console.log/console.warn are showing in release mode) in my App.tsx file useEffect and other methods which should be called when app is launched but none of them show so i think the react native app is not being launched ?

just to detail the project which might help in understanding the app, this app is configured with amplify, redux, redux-sagas and redux-persist .... I tried a lot for atleast 2 days now to just understand where the app is crashing or not launched, but haven't progressed anywhere.

I need help in finding out the cause.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: which package are you using for amplify push notification? and in which platform are you facing issue (android or ios)

Comment: @aws-amplify/pushnotification and @react-native-community/push-notification-ios 
facing this issue on ios .

Comment: Could you share code for how you are navigating on screen when you click on notification.

Comment: Hai There, 
Sorry for the late response . 

after a couple of days observing i found that this happens only when app is sent into background (not terminated) and OS suspends the app, receive a push notification (which launches the app behind the scenes i can see some logs from my App.tsx), and when the app is suspended again after sometime i click on the notification received earlier app just stays on splash screen forever .
i also use react-navigation/native i am still cornered on whats the cause for this .